# Two different player log ins are crossing over mods how do I stop that

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

My bf n I have two PS log ins he downloads mods on his then  he logs out I log in n his mods are in my load order .. keep in mind I log into my own ps account ... he don’t want any mods but if he disabled them it takes my stuff away...how do we stop this